# How to disable when "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" checkbox is greyed out

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am running Visual Studio 2008, and developing a DLL that is instantiated by a commercial application.  When the application terminates, I get errors in the debugger about MDA's.  I found an article that says to disable MDA's by turning off the Visual Studio Hosting Process - however, when I go to the Debug tab of my project, that checkbox is checked and greyed out.  How can I either turn off the hosting process altogether, or enable the checkbox?

Comment: You are on the wrong track with this.  Use Debug + Exceptions, open the "Managed Debugging Assistants" node and untick mda's you don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Hans, that did the trick.  From the Debug menu, I picked Exceptions, expanded under MDA (Managed Debug Assistants), and disabled the exception that was plaguing me - in my case, LoaderLock.  Thanks, also, Jared - that explains why it is greyed out for the DLL projects.

Answer (score 1):

The "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process" box is grayed out in the DLL project because a DLL project can't have a hosting process.  The hosting process is only an option for EXE projects.

In order to disable the hosting process you'll need to go to the EXE project which is the startup project and disable the hosting process there.